# Crash on Application recreate

Tags: android

I had report about strange crash from my test user, he have Sony Experia Z1 device with android 4.4.4 on board. Application crash occurred when application restart from background after couple of hours of sleep.
Here Crash logs:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime(10562): Process: com.example.app, PID: 10562
E/AndroidRuntime(10562): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.MyApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45b256a8 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45b256a8 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1474)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1427)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2989)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1546)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1528)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at com.foxykeep.datadroid.requestmanager.RequestManager.execute(RequestManager.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at com.example.managers.BackgroundNetworkManager.loadAppConfig(BackgroundNetworkManager.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at com.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4462)
E/AndroidRuntime(10562):    ... 10 more
D/AndroidRuntime(10588): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm(10588): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415cbd88)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10575): Process: com.example.app, PID: 10575
E/AndroidRuntime(10575): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.MyApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45b21298 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45b21298 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1474)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1427)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2989)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1546)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1528)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at com.foxykeep.datadroid.requestmanager.RequestManager.execute(RequestManager.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at com.example.managers.BackgroundNetworkManager.loadAppConfig(BackgroundNetworkManager.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at com.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4462)
E/AndroidRuntime(10575):    ... 10 more
V/GAV3    (10588): Thread[main,5,main]: Tracking Exception: SecurityException (@Parcel:readException:1474) {main}
V/GAV3    (10588): Thread[main,5,main]: Dispatch call queued. Dispatch will run once initialization is complete.
V/GAV3    (10588): Thread[main,5,main]: Passing exception to original handler.
E/AndroidRuntime(10588): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(10588): Process: com.example.app, PID: 10588
E/AndroidRuntime(10588): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create application com.example.MyApplication: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45af4260 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4465)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:144)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to find app for caller android.app.ApplicationThreadProxy@45af4260 (pid=997) when starting service Intent { cmp=com.example.app/com.example.services.exampleRequestService (has extras) }
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1474)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1427)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startService(ActivityManagerNative.java:2989)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1546)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1528)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at com.foxykeep.datadroid.requestmanager.RequestManager.execute(RequestManager.java:279)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at com.example.managers.BackgroundNetworkManager.loadAppConfig(BackgroundNetworkManager.java:82)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at com.example.MyApplication.onCreate(MyApplication.java:76)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4462)
E/AndroidRuntime(10588):    ... 10 more
I/Process (10575): Sending signal. PID: 10575 SIG: 9
I/Process (10562): Sending signal. PID: 10562 SIG: 9
```

After this crash, app restart normally. 
But I can not reproduce this issue on my side, seems that all is working fine to me.
Is anybody can help me with this issue? Also Is anybody know, why application restart happened in 3 process simultaneously, not in 1 as general?

Comment: com.example.MyApplication code pls

Comment: @GrisHu I have provided crash log. In this crash log you can see that The issue related with start service method. What more do you need?